# SQL join query failing to remove duplicates for actors in same movie?

Tags: sql, join

I want to list all actors that have participated in a movie with Kevin Bacon. There are three tables: ACTORS (id, full_name)
CAST (actor_id, movie_id)
MOVIES (id, title)

Right now I can't seem to remove duplicates or Kevin Bacon himself. What's wrong with my query?

```
SELECT DISTINCT actors.full_name, movies.title 
FROM actors INNER JOIN cast ON actors.id = cast.actor_id 
INNER JOIN movies ON movies.id = cast.movie_id
WHERE movies.id IN (SELECT movies.id FROM actors INNER JOIN cast ON actors.id = cast.actor_id INNER JOIN movies ON cast.movie_id = movies.id 
WHERE actors.full_name = "Kevin Bacon") AND actors.full_name != ”Kevin Bacon”
```

Comment: Do you want only the actor's name or the titles of the movies also?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to list all actors that have participated in a movie with Kevin Bacon.

This suggests `IN` or `EXISTS`:

```
select a.*
from actors a
where exists (select 1
              from cast c join
                   cast c2
                   on c.movie_id = c2.movie_id join
                   actors a2
                   on c2.actor_id = a2.id
              where a2.full_name = 'Kevin Bacon' and
                    c.actor_id = a.id
             );
```

The inner `from` clause is doing all the interesting work.  The self-join on `cast` is creating all pairs of actors in the same movie.  The `where` then checks that one is Kevin Bacon and the other is connected to the outer query.  You can add `and c2.actor_id <> c.actor_id` to the inner query if you want to eliminate Kevin Bacon himself.

Comment: I tried it in mysql and it gave me a syntax error for the last few lines

Answer (score 0):

The table `movies` is not needed because you can get the id of a movie from the table `cast`:

```
SELECT a.full_name, m.title 
FROM actors a
INNER JOIN cast c ON a.id = c.actor_id 
WHERE a.full_name <> 'Kevin Bacon'
AND c.movie_id IN (
  SELECT c.movie_id 
  FROM actors a INNER JOIN cast c 
  ON a.id = c.actor_id 
  WHERE a.full_name = 'Kevin Bacon'
)
```

If you want only the actor's name, you can join 2 copies of `actors` and `cast` like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.full_name 
FROM actors a1
INNER JOIN cast c1 ON a1.id = c1.actor_id
INNER JOIN cast c2 ON c2.movie_id = c1.movie_id
INNER JOIN actors a2 ON a2.id = c2.actor_id 
WHERE a2.full_name = 'Kevin Bacon' AND a1.full_name <> a2.full_name
```